# Eclipse making apps run with a jerking motion

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl-es

I have found that when eclipse installs and runs opengl apps on my phone and on my tablet the apps run with a jerky motion.

This has recently started happening and it happens with all my projects (all of which used to run fine).

I have tried disabling debugging on the devices and then re-enabling it and also I've cleaned the projects and re started eclipse but that doesn't help.

Does anyone have any idea what I have done to eclipse to make this happen?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't run on phones and tablets so what are you actually doing?

Comment: Sorry - I meant I am using eclipse on my PC to create android apps. I connect my phone to the pc and then run the project. Eclipse builds and installs the app and then runs it on the phone. All my projects used to work fine but now they are all running really jerky.

Comment: Then this is an Android question as Eclipse is just a tool you use. I have updated the question tags.

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought that perhaps it was a setting in Eclipse that was causing it hence I tagged Eclipse. All the other Apps I have purchased from the play store run fine - it's only those I install using eclipse which are going wrong.